# How to compute colorness/ intensity of a color in an image?

Tags: image-processing, colors, hsv, color-space, lab-color-space

I would like to compute a metric which provides me a value which is should be higher if a given color is a light color (for example: light red) or a low value if the same color is a dark color (dark red). This metric should be invariant of the illumination of the light. Of course, I believe complete illumination resistance is not possible, however, it should be somehow robust against it.

Followings are some of my ideas for a specific case of red color (since, I want it illumination invariant, therefore, I start analyzing the colors in HSV and LAB color space):

1. **LAB color space**: Segment A* channel based on the positive values since A channel extends from -128 (Blue) to +128 (Red). So, I assume that I get a segmented red regions/pixels and now, I am interested in knowing the intensity of each of red pixels (in other words, I would like to have a red color intensity map).

   To quantify the red pixels, first thing can be done is to use segment A* channel itself and by looking into the A* values meaning that lower positive A* pixels values should be dark red while higher positive A* pixels values should be light red. However, there is a problem that if I compare A* values of red pixels within an image, then these values does not really correspond to the perceived red color from the original image and also, second problem is that I cannot compare two images with different levels of redness since the values are not correctly normalized or they are not consistent.

   Another thing that can be done is to look into the corresponding values of L* channel which provides the lightness. In other words, we can compute how much light is added to the pure red color. However, this approach is highly sensitive to illumination which makes sense since L* channel is basically provides the light reflectance. Another solution can be to correct the illumination in the L channel (but how?) and then look at the L values. But, I believe this is again not an easy problem.
2. **HSV color space**: Segment hue channel based on the values between 10 - 350 degrees, since this represent a red color. And, then look at the corresponding values of saturation (which tells the purity of color or colorness or amount of gray added to the pure color). Corresponding saturation values would provide the intensity map of the red color? What about V (value)? However, I assume again that V is highly sensitive to the illumination.

   I feel already some problems here with HSV approach: first, segmenting using the Hue channel might not the best way, since the colors are not that well separated. I would expect some outliers here.

   Another approach can be to use A* channel for red color segmentation and then, look at the corresponding values of the S channel in order to know the intensity map of the red color in the image. Is this makes more sense?

At the end, let's assume that we have an illumination corrected image and now, does a combination of either A* channel and L channel or combination of H channel and S channel or A* channel and S channel work to solve this problem?

It would be grateful if somebody provide insight on the above proposed approaches or is there any other better color space or combination of different channels or any other approach where first a red color image (with different shades of it) can be segmented and then, quantify the intensities of these red pixels (from dark red to light red).

Comment: You have provided the solution yourself. You can present this as an answer. Surely the `L channel` from LAB color space and the `Hue` from the HSV color space are the best methods out there